# My Lenovo Y50 isn't detecing the integrated webcam

Tags: drivers, 20.04, webcam

I know similar questions have been asked but I have read the answers on them but none is helping me solve the issue I'm having with my webcam. I've never used my webcam much. Even on the Windows days. After moving to Linux, specifically Ubuntu, I had it covered with a tape for the most part. But the recent events in the world have made video conferencing a necessity I'm trying to see if there are ways to fix the integrated webcam in my Lenovo Y50-70. I have tried a lot of things so far and had given up a while. But yesterday, I opened Cheese by accident and I saw the webcam activity light come on. This was a big surprise. I peeled the tape and there it was... The camera was working. I was ecstatic. Fast forward to today and Cheese or any other app that can access the webcam isn't detecting it anymore. I haven't done anything. No updates. No new apps. The laptop has been shutdown though, and I feel like whatever fixed the webcam was gone with the shutdown.

Here are some details. The Laptop is a Lenovo Y50-70. Running `lspci` returns this:

```bsh
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
0a:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Running `lsusb` shows this (I have an external mouse and keyboard attached):

```bsh
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0489:e07a Foxconn / Hon Hai BCM20702A0
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 258a:1006 Gaming KB  Gaming KB 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 18f8:1686 [Maxxter] USB GAMING MOUSE 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`/dev/video*` doesn't exist on the machine either. I had given up on this webcam a while back. But the fact that it worked yesterday gave me hope. Can anyone shed some light on this issue.

Much appreciated, thanks.